# How to Change the icon Mouse Pointer if i Hover a coordinate area

Tags: python, registry, autohotkey

How can i Change the icon from the Mouse Pointer.

**I want this :** if i Hover with my Mouse Device a special x,y coordinate area, that it will automatic change the icon of the Mouse Pointer (if i reach that area) and if i go outsite that area it must change it back to the default icon.

I have did try to make the code with autohotkey Languages.

But this does not work.

1 - I need to press the F7 key on my keyboard.

2 - And i must restart my computer for changing the icon of my mouse pointer.

```
f7::
RegWrite, REG_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Control Panel\Cursors\,Arrow,%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_link.cur
return
```

(If you have a Code example that is writing in other Scripting Languages like Python or Msdos that is for me ok.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AutoHotkey** - The code below is showing that you can change cursor at a fixed location, in this case the middle of of the screen. How this was accomplished was by using built variables A_screenHeight and A_screenWidth to define Upper/Lower and Right/Left bounds. Then using a Timer and checking if our cursor was within those bounds by using the GetMousePos command. If the mouse is within bounds a  function SetSystemCursor(), coded by Serenity on AutoHotkey Forums, is called, this function uses various DllCall's to change cursor.

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance Force

CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

Left := Round((A_screenWidth / 2) / 2)
Right := Left * 3
Up := Round((A_screenHeight / 2) / 2)
Down := Up * 3

SetTimer, WatchCursor, 100
OnExit, CleanUp
return

WatchCursor:
MouseGetPos, x, y 
If (x >= Left && y >= Up && x <= Right && y <= Down) 
    applied ?: SetSystemCursor("IDC_CROSS"), applied := true
else 
    (!applied) ?: RestoreCursors(), applied := false
return

cleanUp:
RestoreCursors()
ExitApp
Return

esc::GoSub, CleanUp



; https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/32608-changing-the-system-cursor/
SetSystemCursor( Cursor = "", cx = 0, cy = 0 ) 
{
    BlankCursor := 0, SystemCursor := 0, FileCursor := 0 ; init

    SystemCursors = 32512IDC_ARROW,32513IDC_IBEAM,32514IDC_WAIT,32515IDC_CROSS
    ,32516IDC_UPARROW,32640IDC_SIZE,32641IDC_ICON,32642IDC_SIZENWSE
    ,32643IDC_SIZENESW,32644IDC_SIZEWE,32645IDC_SIZENS,32646IDC_SIZEALL
    ,32648IDC_NO,32649IDC_HAND,32650IDC_APPSTARTING,32651IDC_HELP

    If Cursor = ; empty, so create blank cursor 
    {
        VarSetCapacity( AndMask, 32*4, 0xFF ), VarSetCapacity( XorMask, 32*4, 0 )
        BlankCursor = 1 ; flag for later
    }
    Else If SubStr( Cursor,1,4 ) = "IDC_" ; load system cursor
    {
        Loop, Parse, SystemCursors, `,
        {
            CursorName := SubStr( A_Loopfield, 6, 15 ) ; get the cursor name, no trailing space with substr
            CursorID := SubStr( A_Loopfield, 1, 5 ) ; get the cursor id
            SystemCursor = 1
            If ( CursorName = Cursor )
            {
                CursorHandle := DllCall( "LoadCursor", Uint,0, Int,CursorID )   
                Break                   
            }
        }   
        If CursorHandle = ; invalid cursor name given
        {
            Msgbox,, SetCursor, Error: Invalid cursor name
            CursorHandle = Error
        }
    }   
    Else If FileExist( Cursor )
    {
        SplitPath, Cursor,,, Ext ; auto-detect type
        If Ext = ico 
            uType := 0x1    
        Else If Ext in cur,ani
            uType := 0x2        
        Else ; invalid file ext
        {
            Msgbox,, SetCursor, Error: Invalid file type
            CursorHandle = Error
        }       
        FileCursor = 1
    }
    Else
    {   
        Msgbox,, SetCursor, Error: Invalid file path or cursor name
        CursorHandle = Error ; raise for later
    }
    If CursorHandle != Error 
    {
        Loop, Parse, SystemCursors, `,
        {
            If BlankCursor = 1 
            {
                Type = BlankCursor
                %Type%%A_Index% := DllCall( "CreateCursor"
                , Uint,0, Int,0, Int,0, Int,32, Int,32, Uint,&AndMask, Uint,&XorMask )
                CursorHandle := DllCall( "CopyImage", Uint,%Type%%A_Index%, Uint,0x2, Int,0, Int,0, Int,0 )
                DllCall( "SetSystemCursor", Uint,CursorHandle, Int,SubStr( A_Loopfield, 1, 5 ) )
            }           
            Else If SystemCursor = 1
            {
                Type = SystemCursor
                CursorHandle := DllCall( "LoadCursor", Uint,0, Int,CursorID )   
                %Type%%A_Index% := DllCall( "CopyImage"
                , Uint,CursorHandle, Uint,0x2, Int,cx, Int,cy, Uint,0 )     
                CursorHandle := DllCall( "CopyImage", Uint,%Type%%A_Index%, Uint,0x2, Int,0, Int,0, Int,0 )
                DllCall( "SetSystemCursor", Uint,CursorHandle, Int,SubStr( A_Loopfield, 1, 5 ) )
            }
            Else If FileCursor = 1
            {
                Type = FileCursor
                %Type%%A_Index% := DllCall( "LoadImageA"
                , UInt,0, Str,Cursor, UInt,uType, Int,cx, Int,cy, UInt,0x10 ) 
                DllCall( "SetSystemCursor", Uint,%Type%%A_Index%, Int,SubStr( A_Loopfield, 1, 5 ) )         
            }          
        }
    }   
}

RestoreCursors() 
{
   SPI_SETCURSORS := 0x57
   DllCall( "SystemParametersInfo", UInt,SPI_SETCURSORS, UInt,0, UInt,0, UInt,0 )
}
```

Comment: @ahkcoderThis is exact what i did looking for, i did test it out - and it works. 

I did compared it in my Win Registry.
(if i reach that area)

IDC_CROSS is the icon that will be changed into cross_r.cur
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors\Crosshair\%SystemRoot%\cursors\cross_r.cur 

and if i want to change the icon.
then i can replace IDC_CROSS into IDC_HAND 

in codeline: applied ?: SetSystemCursor("IDC_CROSS"), applied := true

IDC_HAND is the icon that then will be changed into aero_link.cur
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors\Hand\%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_link.cur

Comment: Yes, just change the value passed into SetSystemCursor() to SetSystemCursor("IDC_HAND"). 

A list of System Icons: 

IDC_ARROW
IDC_IBEAM 
IDC_WAIT 
IDC_CROSS 
IDC_UPARROW 
IDC_SIZE 
IDC_ICON
IDC_SIZENWSE 
IDC_SIZENESW 
IDC_SIZEWE 
IDC_SIZENS 
IDC_SIZEALL 
IDC_NO
IDC_HAND 
IDC_APPSTARTING 
IDC_HELP 

Can you please accept this as Answered?

Comment: Added some additional code to reduce function calls to restorecursors and an onexit sub routine to guarantee that cursor is restored.

Comment: @ahkcoderAbout accept Answered - I am new Here, And i did find out now, How You can accept the Answered - first i did think if you give on Stack overflow an Upnote that it will automatic then accept the answer, but you need to push the v icon and then it will accept and it will change to color green. maybe in the Future Stack overflow does change the site so, that it will explain better for users how you can do that.

Comment: Thanks for accepting! I know some features are not obvious, I suggest you check out the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)